# Why doesnt @Transactional and @RequestMapping work together?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

The moment I include the @Transactional annotation on a @RequestMapping, I notice in springboot that the url mappings do not auto-configure.

What could be responsible for this?

I want a case where (C)R(UD) rest calls work within a transaction.

Answer (score 0):

If you're goal is to ensure your CRUD operations happen within a transaction, then using Spring Data JPA, this is done for you by default.  Creating a repository interface that extends `CrudRepository` for example, your query methods will inherently be `@Transactional`.  You can customize the `@Transactional` attributes by manually annotating a query method on your repository, but this need only be done if you want non default behaviour.

See the Spring Data JPA docs for more details.
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#transactions

Comment: I understand. My question was to why this is happening not necessarily the solution.

Comment: This is only an assumption, but annotating a method with ```@Transactional``` instructs Spring to create a proxy around your method.  In order to do that, the class needs to implement an interface, at least from what I've read.  I wonder if this process breaks the controller behaviour.